# Angular e2e tests to test non-angular applications

Tags: angularjs

Can angular e2e tests be used to test non-angular applications or would selenium webdriver be a better choice instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly, but initiatives exists.

Both ngScenario (older) and Protractor (newer) are tools that are aware that the System Under Test is angular-based, so you can't really test non-angular based application

Here is an initiative to transform ngScenario so that any framework can be used : http://davidb583.github.io/BlackboxJS